# Python subprocess() reading file in bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I have a shell command for a file as given below:

```
filename="/4_illumina/gt_seq/gt_seq_proccessor/200804_MN01111_0025_A000H35TCJ/fastq_files/raw_data/200804_MN01111_0025_A000H35TCJ.demultiplex.log"

assembled_reads=$(cat $filename | grep -i " Assembled reads ...................:" | grep -v "Assembled reads file...............:")
```

Now I am trying to run this within a python environment using subprocess as:

```
task = subprocess.Popen("cat $filename | grep -i " Assembled reads ...................:" | grep -v "Assembled reads file...............:"", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p_stdout = task.stdout.read()
print (p_stdout)
```

This is not working becasue I am not able to parse the filename variable from python to shell and probably there is a syntax error in the way I have written the grep command.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The quotation marks are not balanced.

Comment: Tried at the beginning of your first line of Python `task = subprocess.Popen(f"cat ${filename} | `... (then the rest of that line) where you use that filename assignment you posted above in Python too? Any chance you can use IPython or Jupyter on your machine? You can use easier options of mixing in bash with Python in those cases.

Comment: The quotation marks are still unbalanced. You must escape the inner `"`s with a `"\"`.

Comment: This works ```task = subprocess.Popen(f"cat {filename}", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)```

Comment: ah, okay, let me try with the escaping !

Comment: If you're going to use Python, you might as well do it all in Python. It would also be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems to solve your problem with no external tools required.

```
filename="/4_illumina/gt_seq/gt_seq_proccessor/200804_MN01111_0025_A000H35TCJ/fastq_files/raw_data/200804_MN01111_0025_A000H35TCJ.demultiplex.log"
for line in open(filename):
    if "Assembled reads" in line and "Assembled reads file" not in line:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go for the pythonic way!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider doing all the reading and searching in python and maybe rethink what you want to achieve, however:

In a shell:

```
$ export filename=/tmp/x-output.GOtV
```

In a Python (note the access to `$filename` and mixing quotes in the command, I also use custom grep command to simplify things a bit):

```
import os
import subprocess
tmp = subprocess.Popen(f"cat {os.environ['filename']} | grep -i 'x'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = tmp.stdout.read()
print(data)
```

Though working, the solution is ... not what I consider a clean code.